# Youtube subscribe pushback notification on playlist not working

Tags: push-notification, youtube

I'm using https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/subscribe to subscribe to pushback when a new video is uploaded to a channel, i have a backend server that receives the feed and it is working, BUT when I enter a playlist link like say https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD7nPL1U-R5r3_key7yI1-aoWMdQQ0I9- it seems to accept it and it sends a challenge to my server, but i get no notification when new videos are added to the playlist.

Does the system not support playlist notifications but only channels?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation [Subscribe to Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications):

> Your PubSubHubbub callback server receives Atom feed notifications when a channel does any of the following activities:
>
> - uploads a video
> - updates a video's title
> - updates a video's description

it seems clear that this feature doesn't support working with arbitrary playlists.